# Send email using google apps script with attachment and mark checkbox as done

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, email-attachments

I am trying to build a script which will be sending emails based on the data in a spreadsheet in google sheets.

```
Column 1 - emailAddress
Column 2 - subject
Column 3 - body
Column 4 - signature
Column 5 - fileName (name of the file I'd like to attach, will be different in each case)
Column 6 - checkbox (new functionality in G Sheets, marked= TRUE, unmarked=FALSE).
```

The aim is to send email only to those which are not marked as sent. After the script is done checkbox should change to TRUE to avoid duplications. 
I wrote the below script however there are two issues:

- How to make a fileName variable value which will be taken to code from column 5?
- How to force the program to change the status of the checkbox to TRUE and to omit those which are already TRUE?

The function:

```
function Email() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = rng.getValues();
  for (i in data)  
    {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var checkbox = data[5]
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(data[4]) 
    var emailAddress = rowData[0];
    var body = rowData[2];
    var subject = rowData[1]; 
    var signature = rowData[3];
    var message = body + '\n\n'+ signature;
      if(checkbox is != 'TRUE')
      {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message, 
      {
        attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
      }
      );
    cell.setValue("TRUE");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to make a fileName variable value which will be taken to code from column 5?**

Create a variable var fileName. For uniqueness purposes just add a counter at the end 1,2, etc so it ends looking like fileName1, fileName2, etc

**How to force the program to change the status of the checkbox to TRUE and to omit those which are already TRUE?**

Use a double for loops because working with sheets is like working with [2D arrays](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). Inside that create an if statement:

if( [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) is != 'TRUE'){

cell.[setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))("TRUE")

}

Hopefully you got the idea from the pseudocode.

Comment: Hi noogui, Thanks for you quick answer, however I am still having problems with the code. Could you please check and let me know how to solve it? 1)Missing ) after condition. (line 15, file "Code") 2)attachment's name is stored in a cell data[4]. How can I refer to that? I changed the code above.

Comment: could you please have a look on this?